# What is the exact difference between “ use_all_dns_ips” and "resolve_canonical_bootstrap_servers_only” in client.dns.lookup options?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

In kafka-client 2.1.0, client.dns.lookup is available. Below is a description of each option.

1. use_all_dns_ips

   when the lookup returns multiple IP addresses for a hostname, they will all be attempted to connect to before failing the connection
2. resolve_canonical_bootstrap_servers_only

   each entry will be resolved and expanded into a list of canonical names

Aren't they both using dns? What are the differences between **use_all_dns_ips** and **resolve_canonical_bootstrap_servers_only** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While both these options are about DNS, they are different:

- `use_all_dns_ips`: When resolving broker hostnames, if multiple IPs are returned for a name, the client will store them all and cycle through all IPs if it gets disconnected.

  More details in the KIP: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-302+-+Enable+Kafka+clients+to+use+all+DNS+resolved+IP+addresses
- `resolve_canonical_bootstrap_servers_only`: When enabled, once a hostname has been resolved, the client is do a reverse lookup to find the FQDN. This can be required in some cases when using SASL GSSAPI.

  More details in the KIP: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-235%3A+Add+DNS+alias+support+for+secured+connection

Comment: Another clear explanation: https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.8/kafka-configuring/topics/kafka-client-dns-lookup-property.html